# can we implement static choice 'ALL' on FM?

Tags: cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8

I have created a stand-alone filter in my framework model (IBM Cognos Framework manager version -8.4.1) for a query subject facility. Please find the expression for it below.

I need to add static value 'ALL' (In value prompt)in my framework model expression. This is possible in Report studio. Please provide the steps for implementing the same in Query studio since I need to implement this in an Adhoc report only.

In simple words, Is it possible to implement static choice ('ALL') in framework manager? Or is there another approach to take?

```
[Patient discharges - Medpar].[Facility].[Facility] in 
(#promptmany('pFacilityName','String','','','[Patient discharges - Medpar].[Facility].[Facility]')# ) and 
[Patient discharges - Medpar].[Facility].[State] in 
(#promptmany('pState','String','','','[Patient discharges - Medpar].[Facility].[State]')# )
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible in FM. The 'All' static choice is only available when you define a control yourself on a prompt page. Value prompts specified in the model will generate a standard system drop-down prompt which doesn't allow that flexibility.

**Workaround:** Add a value prompt to the prompt page of the report using the exact same parameter as specified at the model level (e.g. pFacilityName) and add the static 'All' choice to the value prompt. When the report is run Cognos will recognize that a defined prompt matches the parameter specified in the model SQL and use that instead of the default system prompt it would normally generate.